# What is the difference between proxy_cache_ and fastcgi_cache?

Tags: nginx, proxy, fastcgi, cache

I was searching for a simple Nginx microcache solution and I end up seeing two ways to have microcache. Some tutorials use proxy_cache, while others fastcgi_cache. What are the differences, pros and cons between these two solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Trey are for proxy_pass and fastcgi_pass respectively. There is no point to compare them

Comment: I'm not asking which one is better. I would like know why they are used for microcaching. For microcache purpose, what is the difference between them?

Comment: If you use proxy_pass to access backend you must use proxy_cache. The same for fastcgi_pass/fastcgi_cache.

Comment: Other than that There is no difference between them

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference between the two is the protocol used to communicate with the backend.

`fastcgi_cache` is related to the FastCGI backend protocol. It caches output from FastCGI connected backends.

`proxy_cache` is related to backends that use HTTP as the backend protocol, and it caches output from HTTP connected backends.

Comment: Otherwise they act identically.

Answer (score 2):

fastcgi is used in far more setup assistance for nginx caching than the proxy_cache. You are more likely to run into websites that offer substantive articles for configuring fastcgi caching than for proxy_cache so thats a pro.. to use fastcgi